# Calling Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JSON.net) in a dll (inside Unity) causes exception, while running source with 'dotnet run' works

Tags: c#, .net, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

So, I'm using Newtonsoft's **Json.net** library, and it works great, except that I got a weird case. These are the steps I'm doing:

1. Instantiate a class (simple, with strings as members)
2. Convert it to JSON using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(class1)`
3. Add it to another class as a field (payload)
4. Convert that second class to JSON using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(class2)`
5. run - `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Json)` to a Byte[] variable.

Step 5 works great when I'm running my source files with just `dotnet run`, without anything else. Even when I copy the entire source folder **inside** unity, it works great. The problem starts when I'm compiling to a dll and then trying to use it inside unity. When I do, I get this error:

`TypeLoadException: Could not resolve type with token 01000019 (from typeref, class/assembly System.Text.Encoding, System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral MyClient.CreatePlayer (System.String client, System.String id, System.String type, System.String teamId, System.Single[] location)`

I kept investigating and with the help of the readme file of Json.net, I think I've narrowed it down to a problem with that DLL. According to the readme file, the 'net20' DLL should be used inside unity. And according to Unity, that Json.net DLL's Assembly info targets .NET 3.5. **But** I have other dependencies which require unity's runtime to be ".NET 4.x" Equivalent, including my DLL, So I'm starting to wonder if that could be the problem. Because I have changed the Scripting runtime version to '.NET 4.x, and not 3.0 which is deprecated.
When my source files are inside unity, they use the same 'net20' DLL of Json.net. Maybe building it breaks them?

I'm lost. Can anyone please give me some pointers?

Comment: Instead of describing you code, can you *share* your code with us?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with Json.Net?  The error seems to indicate it is with `System.Text.Encoding` which is not part of Json.Net.  What happens if you take Json.Net of the equation entirely (remove it from your project temporarily) and just use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` on a hardcoded JSON string?  Do you still see the same problem then?

Comment: @BrianRogers, I printed the string to my console, then copied it to a string (and escaped everything), build it, took my DLL into unity, and just ran the simple line of - 
`Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("{{\"type\":\"Spawn\",\"user\":\"client1\",\"payload\":\"{\"entityID\":\"1\",\"entityType\":\"player\",\"teamID\":\"0\",\"location\":[1.0,2.0,3.52]}\"}}"); `

Which is the same JSON i need (notice that it's a JSON inside a JSON, but it doesn't work either way)
It still didn't work!

But it does work when I run from source.

Comment: Well, at least that rules out Json.Net as the source of the problem.

Comment: Then the Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes can't receive a JSON string? Is there another way to convert a JSON string to Byte[]?